# Can Rocket Grab hit Fizz while doing Trickster?

Tags: league-of-legends

When Fizz uses Trickster and becomes untargetable for 1.5-2 seconds, is he immune to being hit by by Blitzcranks Rocket Grab? On the same topic of skill shots, is he immune to all skillshots including ulti skill shots like Ashe's Enchanted Crystal Arrow and Ezreal's True Shot Barrage?

I'm interested in playing Fizz and I'm wondering if a last minute Trickster while running away would save my life against an across the stage ulti when I'm at low health.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it makes you untargetable. Which means that NO skill in game can harm you while E-ing. It's also to make the skill a more satisfying melee gap closer countermove - Jax leap strikes you? E in place. You can then choose to escape with a second E or counter-attack and make it so they can't run from you.

Answer (score 0):

yes fizz's trickster can dodge any skill shots or even target shot's, you can dodge cait's ult le blancs spells even blitz's grab if you time it correctly. It also blocks tower shots

Answer (score 0):

Fizz's playful/trickster is like Vladamir's pool. while he is in the pool he is untargetable by everything.